# In /usr/bin man documentation what does it mean "not installed locally"

Tags: linux, filesystems, directory-structure

The Linux filesystem hierarchy documentation (`man hier`) for `/usr/bin` says:

```
/usr/bin
    This is the primary directory for executable programs.
    Most programs executed  by  normal  users which  are not
    needed for booting or for repairing the system and which
    are not installed locally should be placed in this
    directory.
```

What does *«which are not installed locally»* mean?

Answer (score 6):

It is talking about programs which are not part of the (e.g., Debian) packaging system, e.g., programs which **you** might compile and want to put in a directory without interfering with other programs.  Typically those (locally installed) programs go in `/usr/local`.

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation of the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard (FHS) is that the directories within the `/usr` hierarchy are for files that aren’t **required** for the *local* system to boot up (and connect to a network).

> Most programs executed by normal users which are not needed for booting or
>   for repairing the system and which are not installed locally should be
>   placed in this directory.

This description refers to programs which *may* be installed non-locally, i.e., on a remote server (accessible over a network). This interpretation makes sense when read in context with the following description from `man hier`:

> `/usr`
>   This directory is usually mounted from a separate partition.  It should hold
>   only sharable, read-only data, so that it can be mounted by various machines
>   running Linux.

After a system has booted and connected to a network, directories shared over a network via NFS  (Network File System) can be mounted (read-only) to mount-points within the `/usr` hierarchy.

Comment: This confuses me a little bit. Your reply makes sense but in my Ubuntu PC under `/usr/bin` I find all the software that is local to this machine and installed via `apt-get`. At this point I expected to find these programs to be installed under `/usr/local/bin` because of what the documentation says about `/usr/local`: `This is where programs which are local to the site typically go`. What am I getting wrong?